# Copy Excel print area to Word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I want to copy the print area for landscape in Excel to my Word document, where I run the code from.

I am using

```
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:N33").Copy
```

to copy the area, but as the column width changes, it's useless.

Update:

I am using this to calculate my usable dimensions in my Word Document

```
With ActiveDocument.PageSetup
      UsableWidth = .PageWidth - .LeftMargin - .RightMargin
      UsableHeight = .PageHeight - .TopMargin - .BottomMargin
End With
```

I tried to scale my image to fit with:

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
Selection.ShapeRange.Height = UsableHeight
Selection.ShapeRange.Width = UsableHeight
```

It does not quite do it. The best approach would be to set the image range *before* it copies.

Update2:

```
Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

This gives an error:

```
Set rngTemp = ws.Range("A1")
```

Comment: How do you set the print area while in Excel?

Comment: Well, the problem is that I don't have access to the Excel files. I found a temporary solution where I find the last cell with content and set a range based on that. Not really pleased though

Comment: have you seen this [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176107%28v=office.11%29.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks, Brad. I've seen it and given it a couple of try. Didn't work out in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the print area information using this code:

```
Sub GetPrintArea()

Dim rngPrintArea As Range

'Put print area into range variable
Set rngPrintArea = Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.PageSetup.PrintArea)

'Perform operations on range - shows up in Immediate window:
Debug.Print rngPrintArea.Height
Debug.Print rngPrintArea.Width
Debug.Print rngPrintArea.Cells(rngPrintArea.Rows.Count, rngPrintArea.Columns.Count).Address

End Sub
```

This does not work if a print area is not already set - can you confirm if the Excel sheets are already set to landscape with a print area defined? If not, you'll need to find the paper dimensions and loop through cells until you find those which share the same Left and Top values (I think). You can set the PrintArea like this:

```
'Set print area
Sheet1.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A1:$N33"
```

---

EDIT - This should do what you need now we know that the source dimensions are predefined - you'll need to set UseableWidth and UseableHeight in Word and either bring them into this sub using ByVal or a public variable:

```
Sub FindRange()

Dim rngTemp As Range, rngCopy As Range, rngTest As Range
Dim iCol As Integer, iRow As Integer

Set rngTemp = Sheet1.Range("A1")

'Get closest column
Do Until rngTemp.Left >= UseableWidth
        Set rngTemp = rngTemp.Offset(0, 1)
Loop
iCol = rngTemp.Column

'Get closest row
Do Until rngTemp.Top >= UseableHeight
        Set rngTemp = rngTemp.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
iRow = rngTemp.Row

Set rngCopy = Sheet1.Range("A1", Sheet1.Cells(iRow, iCol))

'Copy rngCopy into Word as you were before

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply MattCrum

Unfortunately the print area is not set. Tested you code and it came out with an error. 

I've though of looping through the cells using for example points, but I didn't find a good method to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes - it won't work if the print area isn't set. You'll need to somehow find whether each cell fits within the dimensions of the landscape page. Is your overall aim to copy a range the size of a piece of A4 paper in landscape orientation to your word document? If so, perhaps you could detect and use the dimensions of the word document?

Comment: That is correct! Landscape with margins. See my updated question, hope you can help.

Comment: Wow, thats really nice! Works like a charm! However, when i run it from Word i get an error. Can you please take a look at my second update to my question? Greatly appreciate it

Comment: How have you defined rngTemp? If you've done it like `Dim rngTemp as Range` then that will be defined as a Word range not an Excel range. Try doing it as `Excel.Range`. Have you added the Microsoft Excel Object Library as a reference?

Comment: Thanks again, Mattcrum. I had to define it as `Excel.Range`. You saved me.